# how to check whether request is made or not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i am using contenteditable property in p tag .. the code is

```
<p contenteditable="true" id="Option1_<?php echo $i ?>" style="width:98%;border:4px thin black; background-color:#D6D6D6;font-size:18px;color:black;padding:3px "><?php echo '&nbsp;'.'A.'.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp'.$question1['Option1'];?></p> 
  <p  contenteditable="true" id="Option2_<?php echo $i ?>" style="width:98%;border:4px thin black; background-color:#D6D6D6;font-size:18px;color:black;padding:3px "><?php echo '&nbsp;'.'B.'.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp'.$question1['Option2'];?></P>
```

and jquery to make a request to make request
document).ready(function(){

```
$("p[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
       var msg = $(".alert");
       var newvalue = $(this).text();
       var field = $(this).attr("id");
       $.post("ajax.php",field+"="+newvalue,function(d){
           var data = JSON.parse(d);
           msg.removeClass("hide");
            if(data.status == '200'){
                msg.addClass("alert-success").removeClass("alert-danger");
            }else{
                msg.addClass("alert-danger").removeClass("alert-success");
            }
           msg.text(data.response);
           setTimeout(function(){msg.addClass("hide");},3000);//It will add hide class after 3 seconds
       });
   });
});
```

and then php to update my mysql database on receiving the request

```
    <?php
$response = NULL;
$status = http_response_code(406);
if(!empty($_POST)){
session_start();
 $mock_test_name=$_SESSION['mock_test_name'];
$num_of_sections = $_SESSION['num_of_sections'];
$school_name = $_SESSION['school_name'];
$class_name = $_SESSION['class_name'];
$section_name = $_SESSION['section_name'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","onlinetest");
      if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
      }
      $table_space = "$school_name $class_name $section_name $mock_test_name";
      $table = str_replace(" ", "_", $table_space);
      $table_space1 = "$school_name $class_name $section_name";
      $table1 = str_replace(" ", "_", $table_space1);
      $table_space2 = "$table1 $table";
      $table2 = str_replace(" ", "_", $table_space2); 
      $table2 = strtolower($table2);
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
         $key = strip_tags(trim($key));
        $value = strip_tags(trim($value));
        $explode = explode("_",$key);
        $user_id = $explode[1];
        $field_name = $explode[0];
        if(isset($user_id)){
            $update = false;
            $selectData = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT " + $field_name + " FROM " + $table2 + " WHERE question_id='" + $user_id + "'"); //Selecting data from MySql
            $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectData); //Fetching Data
            if($result[$field_name]!==$value){ //Checking if the Value is modified
                $update = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE" + $table2+ "SET" + $field_name+"="+$value+ "WHERE question_id='"+$user_id+"'"); //Updating MySQL if value is Modifie
            }
            //Update the users Table
            if($update){
                $response = "User Details Updated";
                http_response_code(200); //Setting HTTP Code to 200 i.e OK
            }else{
                $response = "Not Modified";
                http_response_code(304); //Setting HTTP Code to 304 i.e Not Modified
            }
        }else{
            $response = "Not Acceptable";
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode(array(
    "status"=>$status,
    "response"=>$response
));
?>
```

But i think the request is not made properly as the database is not getting updated.. Please tell me how to check if a request has been made... or am i making error somewhere in writing code ??

Comment: there is an error in your query... just try this   ` "SELECT".$field_name. "FROM". $table2." WHERE question_id="'.$user_id.'" `

Comment: try this `$result[$field_name]!=$value`. If you still getting error just post your error too @Singh Rajput Kushagra

Comment: it is an request made through the html page .... it is not showing any error but the database is not getting updated

Comment: it tried by removing extra = but still the database is not getting updated

Comment: whether you check the select query working fine.. just exit the function after echo the $result value

Comment: my problem is that this php page won't be displayed as an ajax req has been made through jquery. So how do i check anything about that Sql query

Comment: first run your php file separately by passing some default value...or put this code at your php file echo json_encode($result) and console(d) at your ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Your mysqli_query function is formed incorrectly. You have to escape out of the parentheses in order to drop in variables.

You need to do something like

```
mysqli_connect($con, "SELECT " + var1 + " FROM " + var2);
```

or you'll end up making a query for

EDIT:
For a more apt example, the line

```
$selectData = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT $field_name FROM $table2 WHERE question_id='$user_id'");
```

should be

```
$selectData = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT " + $field_name + " FROM " + $table2 + " WHERE question_id='" + $user_id + "'");
```

You'll notice the main difference, especially in coloring between the two, signifying that in the first one, the variables $field_name, $table2, and $user_id are all being interpreted as part of the query. You don't want the NAME of the variable, you want the VALUE of it instead, so you need to concatenate the strings together.

This is just one of the multiple similar fixes you'll need to do for your multiple queries. Every place the editor is marking the thing you're trying to use as a variable as part of the string, take the same steps to concat the strings.

Comment: will the complete format like this mysqli_connect($con, "SELECT " + var1 + " FROM " + var2 + "WHERE"+ var3 + = var4);  ???

Comment: $update = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE" + $table2+ "SET" + $field_name+"="+$value+ "WHERE question_id='"+$user_id+"'");

Comment: so the 2nd statement will be like this $update = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE" + $table2+ "SET" + $field_name+"="+$value+ "WHERE question_id='"+$user_id+"'");

Comment: @SinghRajputKushagra yeah, now you've got it! (Something else I noticed was that $table2 was not declared in your code. Make sure it exists when you call the function or it won't work!) You can also troubleshoot your code by logging with `console.log("UPDATE" + $table2+ "SET" + $field_name+"="+$value+ "WHERE question_id='"+$user_id+"'")` to see if it makes a well formed SQL request

Comment: i have declared $table2 also...... but still the database is not gettiing updated.. i am editing my question by writing complete code for my php script... the main problem is that its kinda ajax request made ... so i can't see the php page directly

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like this,
ajax code

```
$.ajax({
  type:"post",
  url:"ajax.php",
  data: "your data",
 success:function(d){
  console.log(d);
}
});
```

php code:

```
      $table_space = $school_name." ".$class_name." ".$section_name." ".$mock_test_name;
      $table = str_replace(" ", "_", $table_space);
      $table_space1 = $school_name." ".$class_name." ".$section_name;
      $table1 = str_replace(" ", "_", $table_space1);
      $table_space2 = $table1." ".$table;
      $table2 = str_replace(" ", "_", $table_space2); 
      $table2 = strtolower($table2);
```

Comment: now also databse not updated... i am not able to know if the request is made or not

Comment: to conform ajax request just comment the ajax.php content..check whether the post request made or not

Comment: i guess the request is not mde properly